# Result of query set into variable - powershell

Tags: oracle, powershell, sqlplus

I need get result of query into variable - I am working with powershell and sqlplus. My idea is easy and of course doesn't work. Is there any easy way?

I've tried something like this:

```
$query= 'select name from cars where id = 56382301'

$result = sqlplus test/test132@server01 $query

$result
```

Comment: Does `$result = Invoke-Expression "sqlplus test/test132@server01 $query"` help?

Comment: Unfortunately not.. this shows me 'usage'..

Comment: Then it's at least capturing the command output, it's just sounds like the command isn't executing properly. Try putting the `$query` in single quotes

Comment: i ve tried this - Invoke-Expression "sqlplus test/test132@server 'select name from name'" -> same result with usage

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this :

```
$Command.CommandText = "select column1 from table1"

$Reader = $Command.ExecuteReader()
$column1 = $Reader.GetValue(0)
```

Just adapt it to your own parameters